# how to return binary stream from iText pdf converter

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is it possible to return binary stream (byte[ ]) from pdfstamper ?

Basically the objective is to edit PDF doc and replace particular text.

Input already in binary stream (byte[ ])

I worked on C# environment & iText for the PDF editing lib.

Here's my piece of code :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(Mydoc.FileStream);
PdfDictionary dict = reader.GetPageN(1);
PdfObject pdfObject = dict.GetDirectObject(PdfName.CONTENTS);
if (pdfObject.IsStream())
{
PRStream stream = (PRStream)pdfObject;
byte[] data = PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(stream);
stream.SetData(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.    GetString(data).Replace("[TextReplacement]", "Hello world")));
}
FileStream outStream = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);
reader.Close();

return newPDFinStream // this result should be in stream byte[]
```

Understand that **FileStream** need to have output filepath like C:\location\new.pdf

is it possible to not temporary save it ? and directly return the binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just save it to a `MemoryStream` instead:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Odd to have a constructor but not use the newly-created object.
    // Smacks of the constructor doing too much.
    var ignored = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: @Gerry: yes, I suspect you should just put it in a using statement.